# How to call php file into a div?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, include

I'm trying to reload only specific div

```
$("#captcha").html('<?php echo 'abc';?>'); // just as test - works well
```

Because div content is much larger, I tried:

```
$("#captcha").html('<?php include 'myFile.php';?>'); // doesn't work
```

How can I call the code from a .php file into a div ?

Comment: Try `.html("<?php include 'myFile.php'; ?>");`

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: What is the error? Where is your `JavaScript` code? (i.e. separate `.js` file / inline)

Comment: I think you are talking about ajax. You probalby need `.load()` and full urls.

Comment: @Austin Sorry, should have said "make sure you escape any 's in your php output"

Comment: Oh I see, but still, php cannot be run through embedding via javacript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `$('div').load('phpfile.php')`

`$.load` is used to load data from the server via an html file or a server-side script like php.
Just to have an overview of what you can do with `$.load` you can also load page fragments by including a selector after the page you want to retrieve. This way only the contents of the selected element will be loaded into your container. You can also pass in data and execute functions after the request has complete(callbacks).

`$.html` is different because its only used to get or set the contents of an existing element.
You can however use it with ajax methods like `$.post`, `$.get`, `$.ajax` to update the contents
of an existing element.

Read up jQuery's documentation on the [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [$.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) methods
if you want to have an in-depth understanding on how these method works.

Comment: just a moment, I will try these solutions

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu in order for future users/readers to get a grasp of how things work you could consider explaining the difference between the approach @ Alegro tried, this one and others.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried loading the php via ajax? http://api.jquery.com/load/ in case you are working with jquery

Answer (score 1):

Load it to a variable, then sanitize characters. I guess you may have some special chars there that breaks your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is *Preprocessed* (PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor), and cannot be used without a new request. You need to use `load` to load the results of a php file into your javascript. Once the page is loaded, more PHP cannot be run without additional AJAX requests (or other methods that make new requests).

PHP is server-side, meaning that software (PHP) is installed on the server to interpret it *before* the response is sent. An HTTP request is a 'once-and-done' operation, meaning that once a response is sent, the connection between client and server is closed.

Think of PHP and other server-side languages as chefs in a kitchen. Say you order food for pickup, you tell the restaurant what you want and leave to pick it up. You get back to your house and your friend has decided that he wants something from them too. You didn't bring the chefs back with you, only the food they made - so the only way to get your friend's order is to drive all the way back and pick it up again.

I'm sure the above is a grammatical mess (its early), but I hope I got the point accross. Anyways, you will want to use `.load` to load the php file:

```
$("captcha").load('myfile.php');
```

`load` will send an AJAX request to the page `myfile.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `load` method in jquery

Its like

`$('#captcha').load('myFile.php')`

Answer (score -1):

```
<div> 
       <?php include "your_file_name.php"; ?>
</div>
```