# How do I load contents in a table cell?

Tags: php

Not sure if this is possible but I would like to know if I could click a link to a .php file and it loads in a table cell?

See my website I started on: http://farvlu.farmingdale.edu/~schwj13/

On the left, I have the links to the .php files. When I click on them, I would like it to show the original source code in the 'PHP Code:' column and then the result in the 'PHP Result:' column.

Thanks in advance.

Jonathan Schwadron

Comment: yes it is possible. use ajax for this purpose

Comment: It's possible using Javascript, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902554/how-to-call-php-file-into-a-div

Comment: You are going to use javascript, preferably [jquery](http://jquery.com/) + ajax for this kind of job.